# Service Reference Auto Generating Response/Request

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I have a Wcf Project that is using Linq to Sql -- Serialization Mode = unidirectional with a Wpf Project and a MVC 4 Project.

I have a class library that is holding the dbml for the Linq Classes.

And another Class Library that hold the ViewModels for the Wpf Application

I can add a service reference to the Class Library that holds the ViewModels and access the Wcf methods like normal

```
client.DoStuff()
```

Below is the Reference Configuration for the ViewModel C;ass Library

[image]

That generates the Correct Reference.Cs

```
  [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyWebService/DoStuff", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyWebService/DoStuffResponse")]
  MyDataProject.Data.DatabaseModels.DoStuff[] DoStuff();
```

When I create a Web Reference for the Mvc project:

(Same Configuration as above but with a Different ReferenceName)

When executing the same

```
client.DoStuff()
```

I get the error -- Method "DoStuff" has 1 parameter but is invoked with 0 arguments.

Then I look at the Reference.cs file

And the method looks like this:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyWebService/DoStuffResults", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyWebService/DoStuffResultsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    MyWebProject.MyWebSiteReference.DoStuffResultsResponse DoStuffResults(MyWebProject.MyWebSiteReference.DoStuffResultsRequest request);
```

Unchecking Reuse types in referenced assemblies allows me to access the method normally, but then I get type mismatches.

Is their a step I am missing for using Wcf in Mvc?

EDIT-- I updated the Reference I am using for the Wpf client that generates the correct .cs

Then I tried this per replies

[image]

That generates this

```
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyWebService/DoStuff", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyWebService/DoStuffResponse")]
    MyWebProject.MyWebSiteReference.DoStuffResponse DoStuff(MyWebProject.MyWebSiteReference.DoStuffRequest request)
```

Comment: Try unchecking `Reuse types in referenced assemblies` and check `Always generate message contracts`.

Comment: It removed the XmlSerializer attribute, but it is still showing the error.  Updated my Question.

Comment: you can also try setting `ReplyAction="*"`